# How to check if checkbox-unity from ppa:unity-team/ppa succesfully send my report?

Tags: unity, testing, checkbox

I used the checkbox-unity survey to test beta unity 5.0 in Precice.

Completing the survey took me a couple of hours because I thoroughly described the problems I discovered. At the end of the survey I didn't notice that there was a text-field to enter the launchpad login detail and clicked next. An error prompted that sending of the info failed, giving me no option to enter my login-detail and retrying. Clicking 'Previous' regenerated the results and got me back to the login-details. filling my login (no password prompt) and Clicking next displayed 'successful' (within a hundred of a second) but I have the feeling noting has been send.

**Is there a way to verify successful submission?**
I still have the results in a submission.xml file but relaunching checkbox-unity again starts the survey all over again.

I hoped my contribution would be helpful, but if the report isn't submitted, it is useless and disappointing. I found out about the test via http://www.omgubuntu.co.uk/2012/01/unity-5-0-ready-for-testing/

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You can check your last successful upload date here:

- http://results-tracker.ubuntu.com/~YOUR_LAUNCHPAD_USERNAME

With the date, you can then try to find the details of the testrun in this list:

- http://results-tracker.ubuntu.com/ubuntu/precise/+testruns

A bit cumbersome, but it works (note, that it takes a while for results to show up).

Comment: Thx. Now I know that the report wasn't successfully send as I suspected. The results tracker for my launchpad shows for 'Last test run date' 'Never tested'.
A search through the last 10 results (past 15hours) for the submitted 'test runs' doesn't contain my report.
Can I resubmit the manually saved submission.xml or do I have to copy paste my comments and cycle through the tester again?

Comment: If you restart checkbox it should allow you to recover and resend your submission.. if not yes, you can manually submit the submission.xml file in your ~/.checkbox folder to the database